# How do I update the Mac Pro (2013)'s display drivers under Windows?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, mac-pro, gpu, driver

I'm trying to run the HTC Vive setup software (yes, I'm aware the Mac Pro's GPUs are underpowered for VR; I've got an external GPU enclosure on its way, and am trying to do some initial room setup and installation while I wait.); but I'm getting the following error when I attempt to launch `ViveSetup.exe`:

> Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, swapBehaviour 2, swapInterval 1, profile 0). This is most likely caused by not having the necessary graphics drivers installed.
>
> Install a driver providing OpenGL 2.0 or higher, or, if this is not possible, make sure the ANGLE Open GL ES 2.0 Emulation libraries (libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll, and d3dcompiler_*.dll) are available in the application executable's directory or in a location listed in PATH.

Does anyone know how I can upgrade the drivers for Apple's AMD FirePro D700 (which appear to be at "FireGL V") to something supporting OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest Boot Camp support software from Apple?

Comment: I mean, as far as I can tell? It automatically downloads and installs when you boot up the first time; but I've no idea how to update it. Google isn't being helpful — Apple's documentation only says to update macOS before bootcamping (which I did.)

Answer (score -1):

use at your own risk but bootcampdrivers.com may have a solution for you...